# Text qualfier in bulk insert without format file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to import a csv file ('|' delimited though) using bulk insert. The problem is that some columns have text qualifier double quotes. However this is not consistent across all rows in the same column. Inside the double quotes I find the text delimiter '|' which is part of the text, For example

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
1|text1|101
2|"text2|text2a"|102
3|text3|103
4|"text4"|104
```

In this case I can't use the format file where I could specify the column delimiter because col2 does not have consistent delimiter (it is either | or |").

However, if I try to import via the import wizard and select text qualifier '"' then the wizard successfully sorts everything into columns, recognizing '"' as text qualifier and not as column delimiter ("| or |"). Is there an equivalent way using the bulk insert?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, I fixed it. Thanks